# How to specify what data to print with Selenium Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have this code:

```
from keyboard import press_and_release
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url = 'https://www.yr.no/nb'

def weather(url, webdriver):
    webdriver.get(url)  # Goes to the HTML-page of the given URL
    for li_values in webdriver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ol.daily-weather-list__intervals li"):
        print(li_values.text + "\n")


def forecast():
    print('Hello, I can search up the weather for you.')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Amalie\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")  # Open Google Chrome
    driver.get(url)  # Goes to the HTML-page of the given URL

    while True:
        inp = input('Where shall I search? Enter a place in :').capitalize()  # Ask for input
        print('Alright, checking the weather in ' + inp + '...')

        "Search for a place"
        driver.find_element_by_id("page-header__search-button").click()  # Find and click on search input box
        driver.find_element_by_id("page-header__search-input").send_keys(inp)  # Enter input
        press_and_release('enter')  # Click enters
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="page-header__search"]/ol/li[1]').click()  # Click on 1st suggested option
        break
    cURL = driver.current_url
    weather(cURL, driver)

    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
forecast()
```

Which gives me this output:

```
Hello, I can search up the weather for you.
Where shall I search? Enter a place in :bergen
Alright, checking the weather in Bergen...

I dag 14. juni
Ettermiddag: skyet
Kveld: skyet
Maksimum/minimum temperatur:
13°/12°
Nedbør
0,5mm
Vind:
5
m/s
Se time for time





Ettermiddag: skyet

Kveld: skyet

Tirsdag 15. juni
Natt: regn
Morgen: regn
Ettermiddag: delvis skyet
Kveld: skyet
Maksimum/minimum temperatur:
13°/10°
Nedbør
4,6mm
Vind:
4
m/s
Se time for time

Natt: regn

Morgen: regn

Ettermiddag: delvis skyet

Kveld: skyet

Onsdag 16. juni
Natt: skyet
Morgen: regn
Ettermiddag: regn
Kveld: regn
Maksimum/minimum temperatur:
16°/10°
Nedbør
10mm
Vind:
9
m/s
Se time for time

Natt: skyet

Morgen: regn

Ettermiddag: regn

Kveld: regn
```

ETC...

How can I choose to only print the data from today, tomorrow, etc. as shown below:

```
I dag 14. juni
Ettermiddag: skyet
Kveld: skyet
Maksimum/minimum temperatur:
13°/12°
Nedbør
0,5mm

Tirsdag 15. juni
Natt: regn
Morgen: regn
Ettermiddag: delvis skyet
Kveld: skyet
Maksimum/minimum temperatur:
13°/10°
Nedbør
4,6mm
```

I know the xpaths, but I figured I had to use identificators or something like this, but I am very new to HTML so I dont know if there's already a function for this or if I have to write the code myself.

Comment: Hmm... I get only a blank line output from your program...

Comment: I am testing it now, and it seems to only work sometimes and othertimes it just outputs 'Process finished'.. I don't know why that is, so I'll have to figure that out. But when I run it several times I get the desired output 1 in 3 times. All I need to know now is how to just get the desired data and discard the unwanted data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example to get the first two items from the list you can do something like this:

```py
def weather(webdriver):
    webdriver.get(url)  # Goes to the HTML-page of the given URL
    list_xpath = "//ol[@class='daily-weather-list__intervals']/li[@class='daily-weather-list-item']"
    all_items = webdriver.find_elements_by_xpath(list_xpath)
    for li_values in all_items[:2]:
        print(li_values.text + "\n")
```